# I want to locate the specific building the user is in. Should I use html5 geolocation or build my own custom map?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, geolocation, gps

I'm building a web app with google app engine and python. I've read that html5 geolocation is much more precise than IP geolocation, but is that precise enough to pinpoint buildings? Or is building my own map with customized coordinates a better option?

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing two different problems. Coordinates are exactly what HTML5 `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns. Without either HTML5 or IP or some other form of geolocation, you don't have coordinations to look up in the map. With geolocation, you have coordinations… but that's just a set of numbers; you still need to look them up somewhere like Google Maps API to turn it into an address or building.

Comment: HTML5 is a standard where is consists of several geolocation technologies. The wifi geolocation is more precise than the IP address based geolocation. Since wifi is limited to a building distance, you can use it to pinpoint the building. But keep in mind that there is no guarantee all users are in a wifi neighbourhood. You can compare the geolocation technologies from http://www.geolocation.com

Answer (score 1):

How precise HTML5 geolocation is depends entirely on what the user's browser supports.

On a phone, it may have access to the phone's idea of the user's location (based on GPS plus cell and WiFi triangulation); on a desktop machine, there's little to go on besides IPs, so it can't do any better than you could do yourself.

But either way, the user may have disabled or limited it (or it may be disabled or limited by default for him). Or may be using a browser that doesn't support HTML5 locations. Or may be using an add-on that fuzzes or flat-out lies about location.

So:

> is that precise enough to pinpoint buildings?

It can be.

> Or is building my own map with customized coordinates a better option?

How would that help? If you don't know the coordinates the user is at, you have nothing to look up on the map.

Comment: By building my own map I meant having the user input their location based on a pre-constructed map

Comment: @smores: Well, you could have them input their location based on a Google Maps or similar map too. The usual way to do things is to open a map window at the location you detected, and let them manually change it if it's wrong, or maybe let them enter it manually without even trying geolocation. Play around with other services out there and see how they do it to get some ideas.